# Negative result to be shown as "0"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula:

`=NETWORKDAYS(J16;K16;Helgdagar!$A$1:$A$28)-SIGN(NETWORKDAYS(J16;K16;Helgdagar!$A$1:$A$28))`

If the result is negative, I want the result to say "0". How can I do that?

Comment: You want the value to be 0 or is a cell format that displays negatives as 0 acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=Max(NETWORKDAYS(J16;K16;Helgdagar!$A$1:$A$28)-SIGN(NETWORKDAYS(J16;K16;Helgdagar!$A$1:$A$28));0)
```

If you want to keep the negative number but display 0 then use the following Custom Format:

```
0;"0"
```

It will mask any negative numbers as 0, but keep the underlying negative value.

Comment: wow, have it display 0 when excel will treat it in future calculations as a negative value like say -42... I am sure there is some use for this, but I would think it would lead to future potential errors by unsuspecting users.  Still very interesting.

Comment: @ForwardEd you never know what floats the other person's boat.

Comment: If I am still shaking my head about this tomorrow I will let you know.  I just find it scary that I can no longer trust the value displayed in a cell as the value of the cell...its this only a special case for Zero or could a display of 11 actually be a value of 34?

Comment: If you put `"11";0` in for a custom format it will always show 11 for all positive numbers.  Do that to someone at work and watch them freak out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

`=IF(NETWORKDAYS(J16;K16;Helgdagar!$A$1:$A$28)-SIGN(NETWORKDAYS(J16;K16;Helgdagar!$A$1:$A$28))>0;NETWORKDAYS(J16;K16;Helgdagar!$A$1:$A$28)-SIGN(NETWORKDAYS(J16;K16;Helgdagar!$A$1:$A$28));"0")`